# Punching a hole into $\mathbb{R}^\omega$

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ be endowed with the product topology. Is there a nonempty open set $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^\omega$ such that $\mathbb{R}^\omega\cong \mathbb{R}^\omega\setminus \text{cl}(U)$?

(By $\text{cl}(\cdot)$ we denote the topological closure.)

**Edit.** Apologies for omitting the word "open" in the question above.

Comment: And does $\cong$ mean homeomorphic?

Comment: Taking $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R^\omega$ in place of $\mathbb R^\omega$ (as they are homeomorphic), won't $(-\infty,0]\times \mathbb R^\omega$ work?

Comment: @Dominic: maybe you mean  $U$ a compact subset?

Comment: (why this  immediate down-voting? the title suggests that maybe the real question was different)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because -- in its original form at least -- it admits of a one line answer (as demonstrated in the comments).

Comment: Looking at the title rather than the question itself:  is it obvious that $\mathbb R^\omega \setminus \{0\}$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^\omega $?

Comment: Sorry -- I meant *open* set $U$.

Comment: I guess @GeraldEdgar's answer can be made to fit the question as I intended it. Apologies for putting it in a wrong manner

Comment: For infinite dimensional Hilbert space, it is true that any closed half-space is homeomorphic to the whole space. I guess it holds true for several LCTVS, included this one

Comment: Replace $(-\infty,0]$ with $(-\infty,0)$. I'm pretty sure the closure is the same.

Comment: @Goldstern You may want to ask this as a separate question, I would be interested to see an answer.

Comment: Homotopical equivalence of open subsets of $R^\omega$ implies homeophism. $$$$Henderson, David W.; Schori, R.
Topological classification of infinite dimensional manifolds by homotopy type. 
Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 76 1970 121–124.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $U= (-\infty,0) \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \dots$, then 
$\mathrm{cl}(U) = (-\infty,0] \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \dots$, and the complement of this is $(0,+\infty) \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \dots$, which is homeomorphic to the whole space.

Comment: Wojowu beat me to it.

Comment: Edited, to get the changed question with $U$ open.