# Is $\mathbb{R}^\omega \cong (\mathbb{R}^\omega \setminus \{x\})$?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is $\mathbb{R}^\omega  \cong (\mathbb{R}^\omega \setminus \{x\})$, where $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is given the product topology, and $x\in\mathbb{R}^\omega $?

Comment: This question also came up in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301892/punching-a-hole-into-mathbbr-omega

Comment: Yes, any two homotopy equivalent Hilbert manifolds are homeomorphic, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_manifold. The countable product of lines is homeomorphic to the separable Hilbert space, see Bessaga C., Pelczynski A. "Selected Topics in Infinite-Dimensional topology" for much more information.

Comment: In fact, the complement in $\mathbb R^\omega$ of the union of any countable family of compact subsets is homeomorphic to  $\mathbb R^\omega$, see e.g. Theorem V.6.4 in Bessaga-Pelczynski's book.

Comment: Great @IgorBelegradek, thanks! Can you put this into an answer so we can close this thread?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is yes. Any two homotopy equivalent [Hilbert manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_manifold) are homeomorphic. The countable product of lines is homeomorphic to the separable Hilbert space, see p.174 of [Bessaga C., Pelczynski A., Selected Topics in Infinite-Dimensional topology] where much more information is given.

More generally, the complement in $\mathbb R^\omega$ of the union of any countable family of compact subsets is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^\omega$, see e.g. Theorem V.6.4 in Bessaga-Pelczynski's book.

Comment: How is $\mathbb R^\omega$ homotopy equivalent to itself with a point removed?

Comment: The proof of the second statement is also in van Mill's book "infinite-dimensional topology, prerequisites and an introduction", in a self-contained way.

Comment: @Wojowu ... $\mathbb R^\omega \setminus \{0\}$ is contractible and thus homotopic to a point ... unlike $\mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$ and thus contrary to our intuition.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar ...how is it homotopic to a point? Sorry for such silly questions, I have never studied those topics.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/a/199/454

Comment: If you just need a reference use the second paragraph of the answer. If you need a direct proof see the link given by Gerald Edgar.