# Sequences with 0's in $\mathbb R ^\omega$

Tags: gn.general-topology, dimension-theory, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

Let $\mathbb R ^\omega$ be the set of all sequences of real numbers in the product topology.

Let $X$ be the set of all sequences in $\mathbb R ^\omega$ which have at least one 0.

Let $Y$ be the set of all sequences in $\mathbb R ^\omega$ which have at least two 0's.

Are $X$ and $Y$ homeomorphic, and if so, is there a simple proof of this?

Comment: Some of the discussion on [this somewhat similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302279/is-mathbbr-omega-cong-mathbbr-omega-setminus-x) might be relevant to this one.

Comment: (My guess would be that $X$ and $Y$ are both homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^\omega$. Is there any obvious obstruction to this?)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen That will not be the case because they are countable unions of nowhere dense subsets. I think that probably they are each homeomorphic to the pseudo-boundary of the Hilbert cube, but proving that would require some very deep theorems from infinite dimensional topology. I was hoping there would be a simple argument that I just hadn't noticed.

Comment: I'm not an expert on infinite-dimensional spaces, but does being nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ really preclude being homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^\omega$? Naively it seems that the set of sequences beginning with $0$ is nowhere dense but still homeomorphic (by the map which erases the leading $0$ and shifts all other digits left by one place)

Comment: @RonniePavlov correct but $X$ is the union of sets where $x_0=0$, where $x_1=0$, etc. each of which is nowhere dense in $X$. by Baire's theorem $X$ cannot be completely metrizable, so it is not the same as $\mathbb R ^\omega$.

Comment: Again, maybe wrong, but: are these sets really nowhere dense in $X$? Isn't a small enough neighborhood of $(0, 1, 1, 1, ...) \in X$ completely contained in $\{x_0 = 0\}$?

Comment: @RonniePavlov No, basic neighbourhoods in the product only look at finitely many coordinates at a time. It is a product of intervals where all but finitely many are the whole of $\mathbb{R}$: every nonempty open set contains points with infinitely many zeros.

Comment: Is anything known about this if we replace $\mathbb{R}$ by $[0,1]$ and ask the same questions?

Comment: It might be insightful to answer the question first for the product of the discrete space $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: If you replace $\mathbb{R}$ by the Sierpinski space $\mathbb{S}$ then the analogous spaces $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic. The specialization orders of $X$ and $Y$ are then given by the poset of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ with at least one (respectively two) element missing, and these two posets are not isomorphic.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins In the Baire space $\omega^\omega$ both sets are open, hence Polish and nowhere compact. Therefore they are homeomorphic to the Baire space again (Alexandroff: https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01451582).
Here the spaces are of first category; a different kettle of fish.

Comment: @KPHart yes, that is what I had expected—they would both be Polish. But what I was suggesting was that a direct proof that they are homeomorphic in the discrete case might be insightful for the present case, which appears to be difficult to think about.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins for each $n$ the set of points with their first zero at $n$ is clopen and homeomorphic to Baire space; likewise for each pair $(m,n)$ with $m<n$ the set of points with their first two zeros at $m$ and $n$ is clopen and homeomorphic to Baire space.
The spaces are therefore both sums of countably many copies of Baire space and hence homeomorphic.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ the corresponding sets are neither open nor closed (with one exception in each case: $n=0$ and $(m,n)=(0,1)$; those two are closed, but still not open).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For every $n\in\mathbb N$ consider the space
$$X_n=\{x\in\mathbb R^\omega:\lvert x^{-1}(0)\rvert\ge n\}.$$

**Theorem.** For any positive integer numbers $n<m$, the spaces $X_n$ and $X_m$ are not homeomorphic.

*Proof.* The spaces $X_n$ and $X_m$ are not homeomorphic because the space $X_m$ is a $\sigma Z_{m-1}$-space whereas $X_n$ is not.

Let us recall that a *closed* subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is a *$Z_k$-set* in $X$ if the set $C([0,1]^k,X\setminus A)$ is dense in the function space $C([0,1]^k,X)$ endowed with the compact-open topology. A topological space $X$ is called a *$\sigma Z_k$-space* if $X$ is the countable union of $Z_k$-sets.

$Z_k$-sets are higher-dimensional counterparts of nowhere dense sets and $\sigma Z_k$ are counterparts of meager spaces.

Since any singleton in $\mathbb R^m$ is a $Z_{m-1}$-set, the space
$X_m$ is a $\sigma Z_{m-1}$-space. Assuming that $X_m$ is homeomorphic to $X_n$, we would conclude that $X_n$ is a $\sigma Z_{m-1}$-space. Consider the closed subset $A=\{0\}^n\times\mathbb R^{\omega\setminus n}\subseteq X_n$ of $\mathbb R^\omega$ and observe that $A$ is not a $Z_n$-set in $\mathbb R^\omega$.  Since $X_n$ is a $\sigma Z_{m-1}$-space, $A=\bigcup_{i\in\omega}A_i$ is a countable union of $Z_{m-1}$-sets $A_i$. Since $n\le m-1$, each $Z_{m-1}$-set $A_i$ is a $Z_n$-set and hence the set $C([0,1]^n,X_n\setminus A_i)$ is dense in $C([0,1]^n,X_n)$.
It can be shown that the set $C([0,1]^n,X_n)$ is dense in $C([0,1]^n,\mathbb R^\omega)$ and hence $C([0,1]^n,X_n\setminus A_i)$ is dense in $C([0,1]^n,\mathbb R^\omega)$, which means that $A_i$ is a $Z_n$-set in $\mathbb R^\omega$ (being a closed subset of the closed subset $A$ of $\mathbb R^\omega$). By the proof of Lemma 2.7 in the paper [Concerning locally homotopy negligible sets and characterization of $l_2$-manifolds](https://bibliotekanauki.pl/articles/1364141) of Toruńczyk, the completeness of $\mathbb R^\omega$ implies that the closed $\sigma Z_n$-set $A=\bigcup_{i\in\omega}A_i$ is a $Z_n$-set in $\mathbb R^\omega$, which is not true. $\quad\square$

Comment: Very surprising! Thank you

Comment: @D.S.Lipham You are wellcome. Today I looked at unanswered questions in tag "gn" and found this your interesting question at the very top of the stack. It is strange that I have not noticed it earlier (it was posed almost a year ago, probably, because of the summer and vacances).